# CMake cannot find a C and C++ compiler while installing DLib in a Python Virtualenv

Tags: python, c++, cmake, compiler-errors

after watching a tutorial on facial recognition with Python, I managed to write w working program on my Linux laptop. Today I was trying to do the same thing on my Windows 10 PC but I keep getting errors when trying to install DLib from the source code using:

```py
python setup.py install
```

The error message that I get goes like this:

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing dlib.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to dlib.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to dlib.egg-info\top_level.txt
package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
reading manifest file 'dlib.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
no previously-included directories found matching 'tools\python\build*'
no previously-included directories found matching 'dlib\test'
writing manifest file 'dlib.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win32\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
Building extension for Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:21:23) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]
Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake D:\Pyton_Pliki\facial_recognition\Lib\site-packages\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=D:\Pyton_Pliki\facial_recognition\Lib\site-packages\build\lib.win32-3.8 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\kubus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=D:\Pyton_Pliki\facial_recognition\Lib\site-packages\build\lib.win32-3.8'
-- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
-- Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.18362.
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.
```

I have VS 16 2019 installed and I installed CMake both using the Windows installer and from the VS tools.
I know that the problem is with the compiler but how do I install one and point CMake to it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/vscpp-step-0-installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link helped:

learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/vscpp-step-0-installation

I followed the process of installation of C++ compiler using Visual Studio which was described in detail in this article. After that I run `python setup.py install` and everything worked fine.

Thanks to Stark!

Comment: @squareskittles I edited my answer so it provides more info. Hope it's ok now!